# Get all documents in a Document library using SharePoint 2010 services and Javascript

Tags: 2010, document-library, rest, listdata.svc

I am trying to retrieve all documents in a document library using SharePoint 2010 Services (Listdata.svc or lists.asmx) and JavaScript. I have searched on Internet and found some, none of them gets one single list (document library) almost all get all lists. What is the best solution to get all documents in a document library using SharePoint services and JavaScript?

Comment: You want to download documents or only want netadata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can user following URL to get all listitems in list

```
http://<sharepoint-server>/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/<ListName>
```

You can use this service in your javascript code.

To get listitems in javascript using JSOM:

```
function retrieveListItems(siteUrl) {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Announcements');

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml(
        '<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' + 
        '<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query>' + 
        '<RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>'
    );
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(collListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
    ); 
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    var listItemInfo = '';
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() + 
            '\nTitle: ' + oListItem.get_item('Title') + 
            '\nBody: ' + oListItem.get_item('Body');
    }

    alert(listItemInfo.toString());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + 
        '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: How do you get the attachments?

Comment: http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2013/06/27/how-to-get-list-item-attachments-using-rest-and-javascript-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/91488b94-fe55-479b-9d26-a8f542e902c5/who-to-get-the-attachment-file-name-from-sharepoint-list-using-ecmascript?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious

Comment: Aanchal When I use your csom code it generates this error. Value does not fall within the expected range parameter serverRelativeUrl when it comes to new SP.ClientContext(url). I am sending whole url of the site (http://app.com/sites/sc1)

Comment: and regarding your comments, I am using SP 2010

Comment: check again it should not give error on SP.ClientContext(url)

Comment: Make sure you're passing the url along with the protocol unless it's relative url. 


retrieveListItems('https://app.sharepoint.com/sites/sc1');